# Creating phyllotactic flower in blender 3.0

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to create a [phyllotactic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phyllotaxis) flower (one whose leaves form a particular kind of pattern, usually spiral,) in blender as a part of my journey to learn geometry nodes. I was following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqRVxosrnGc&t=68s) but I am not sure what exactly am I doing wrong.

This is my [raw blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BfgBgS8R7hyNuHHMT9g8hp2NBrRjnJmB/view?usp=sharing).

Can anyone please explain to me where exactly am I going wrong?

Comment: For us non-botanists: What is a phyllotactic flower?

Comment: Could you explain here what is wrong? Or are we supposed to discover it by ourselves?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you are following a tutorial and something goes wrong, generally it means that you failed to follow it correctly. In general this is really fine and to be expected. This happens to everybody all the time. Struggling is normal when learning. The simplest solution to this kind of a problem is always to start over and attempt to follow it from the beginning as many times as it is required for you to get it right. This way you learn what it is attempting to teach and also to troubleshoot problems so this is not in any way wasting time as it may seem.

Comment: I have been trying to follow it exactly how the guy tells it in the video and I know there is something silly that is the root of this problem. And thus I thought perhaps I need a fresh perspective which in turn got me here.

Comment: I too had the same issue. I had to rewatch the tut and redo this over and over to find the fix which was really simple
- For modelling the leaf, the author uses a circle and ROTATES it in the X-axis at 90º.
- Then aligns the leaf to point upwards, which is another rotation. So, in the object properties,the Rotation X should be 180º. 
But it seems like, after modelling the leaf, he has applied the rotation (Ctrl + A) and then rotated it again. So, if you check in the video, the object properties panel will show the rotation to be only 90º. On doing this, the issue got solved